# Is it possible to override the logic of Acumatica Login?

Tags: authentication, acumatica

I want to implement password history.

I am wondering if its possible to change the behavior of login of acumatica.
Is it possible through customization? If not, what other chances to possibly modify it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge login page is not customizable using the customization project editor. The changes to login page need to be deployed by manually copying them in the IIS virtual directory folder instead of packaging them in a customization.

A solution depending on this would be rejected by Acumatica ISV certification program. SAAS deployment would be problematic too.

The files are in the 'Frames' folder and the logic is in 'Login.aspx.cs':
[image]